# Python checking if all item in nested list are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

Simple question how would you find that all the elements in a nested list are equal to 0 or specific value
my code goes like this

```
a = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
def checkall(a):
    zeros = 0
    for i in a:
        for b in i:
            if b==0:
                zeros+=1
            else:
                break
```

is there any other better way to do this? without importing any libraries

Comment: Your current code doesn't attempt to determine if all elements in the list are zero. It will return `None` in any case

Comment: You have `all` and `any` to make this easier

Comment: @ForceBru i tried putting an if statement where len(a)==zeros then print('all values are 0') but len(a) is only 2 so that does not work as well

Comment: The simplest way I can think of is `[all(j==0 for j in i) for i in a]`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all sublists of `a` and check if the count of 0s is equal to the length of the sublist, meaning it contains only 0s, and then check if all of the resulting values are `True`:

```
a = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
def checkall(a):
    return all(el.count(0) == len(el) for el in a)
```

This results in

```
>>> checkall(a)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The following expression returns `True` if all elements are 0 (or False), else return `False`

```
not any(any(x) for x in a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension:

```
b = [True if d==0 else False for i in a for d in i]
all(b)
```

The first line creates a list of boolean values (True if the element is zero, False otherwise). Then the second line checks if all the list consists of True values.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
def checkNested(ls,n):
    total = 0
    for i in ls:
        total += i.count(n)
    return total
```

Where `ln` is the list (must have nested lists) and `n` is the number you are checking. It returns the total n's found in your nested lists. `checkNested([[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])` returns 6.

Comment: But that doesn't check that all the elements are equal to `n`. You'd need to do another calculation to get the combined length of all the mested lists, and then compare that with your total.

Comment: But isn't that what `list.count` is for? I thought by iterating through all the nested lists in `ln` and calling i's count method would add the frequency of `n` in 'i' to the total.

Comment: What would you do with that return value of `6`? It's only useful if you know the sum of the lengths of the nested lists. Because if that also equals `6`, you then know that ***all*** the elements are the same (which is what the OP is asking for). So your function should accumulate the lengths of `i` in the loop, and then return `total == length`.

Comment: Oh right - I assumed from the code excerpt in the question that the OP was actually trying to count the number of 0's in the nested list.

Answer (score 0):

A simple function can do this:

```py
def is_sublists_equal(master_list:list, element)->bool:
    '''
    Checks if all sublists are equal to given item
    '''
    i=0
    if master_list[0][0]!=element:
        return False
    while master_list[0]==master_list[i]:
        i+=1
        if i>(len(master_list)-1):
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Example:

```py
is_sublists_equal([['a','a','a'], ['a','a','a'], ['a','a','a']], 'a') #returns True
is_sublists_equal([['a','a','a'], ['a','b','a'], ['a','a','a']], 'a') #returns False
is_sublists_equal([['a','a','a'], ['a','a','a'], ['a','a','a']], 'b') #returns False
```